# Vue 3 - Router is working but not rendering components

Tags: javascript, linux, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

When I build my Vue project, (router history mode), it only shows the navbar and commented the < router-view > element.

On local machine, it works as expected, rendering some basic content.

Here are some appropriate files:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <Head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="prefetch stylesheet">
  </Head>
  <Navbar/>
  <router-view/>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import Navbar from "@/components/includes/Navbar.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  props: {
  },
  components: {
    Navbar
  }
});
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import "assets/css/general";
</style>
```

Router's **index.ts**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: import('@/views/Home.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/tv',
    name: 'television',
    component: import('@/views/Television.vue'),
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

Apache is configured well. I can't really see the mistake, when I build production version, it is without error.

Comment: Have you found a solution for that? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Danny_DD It has been a while, but I believe it has to do something with vue.config.js -> publicPath item. Try adding:
publicPath: '/'
to config.